# Can you run two test cases simultaneously in a Test Suite in Microsoft Test Manager 2010?

Tags: testing, microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to create a unit test to run on two machines in Microsoft Test Manager 2010. In this test I want some client and server side test code to run simultaneously; the client side test being dependent on server side test working successfully.

When putting together a Test Suite in Test Manager, I want to be able to set both tests to have the same order value (so they run at the same time) but the validation prevents this; setting the order as shown below:
[image: Test Suite]

Is there any way I can achieve the simultaneous test execution I am after?

Comment: How can they run simultaneously if one is dependent on the other?

Comment: The server exposes some data to be consumed by the client. The client then does something with that data and sends it back to the server.

The server could fail at the first hurdle however, e.g. starting the WCF service in this case and I would like this error to be recorded in the test result of 'Server Test'. If this failure occurred of course, the 'Client Test' would also fail but this is correct as it cannot communicate with the server to proceed with it's side of the test.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: That is about as far from a "unit" test as you can get. Can you not mock out the behavior and perform each test in isolation?

Comment: Totally agree actually, the tag is misleading, it is not a unit test, it is a very high level system integration test really. I just want to utilise Test Manager's ability to distribute components between machines and log success and failure of those components in a test result. Maybe it is the wrong tool for the job and if so I'd be grateful for any suggestions as to an alternative? Thanks for your time so far.

Comment: Are these Test Cases automated by your "unit tests"?
How do you want to start the tests? (manual: from Test Manager? using a bat file? automatically: using a build definition?)
Is it essential for you to have both tests outcomes in a single test result file?

Comment: The tests will be started automatically by a build definition as a nightly integration test. It is not essential that both test outcomes appear in test outcome file but I need them to run at the same time as they are dependent on each other. There is one alternative to this which is to setup the server-side test running as an external application on the server machine for the client test communicate with. The only problem with this is that there is no way of capturing server-side errors in a clean way like a test result file.

Comment: Are you using LabDefaultTemplate in this build definition? If "Yes": what does this build definition do? Will it start a "real" build building your code? Will it deploy the last build on test environment?
If "No": how are you going to start the tests? Using tcm.exe? Sorry for so many questions but I want to understand exactly what your test environment is looking like. Since you will definitely not be able to set the same order value to both test cases via MTM I'm trying to suggest another solution.

Comment: No problem on the questions, I am grateful for your help! I am using the LabDefaultTemplate that builds the latest code, deploys the latest code and then runs a Test Suite from Test Manager. Ideally, I'd like the server test to run on one machine and the client test to run on another. Then, when both test are complete test results for the client test and server test will be collected and presented after the build.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer... I've missed the notification about your answers to my question :-( Sorry for that!

In case you are still looking for solution, here my suggestion.

I suppose you have a test environment consisting of two machines (for server and client).
If so, you will not be able to run tests on both of them, or better to say you will not have enough control over running tests. Check [How to Run automated tests on multiple computers at the same time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff950318%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) 
Actually I posted a related question to "Visual Studio Development Forum", you could check the answers I got here: [Is it possible to run test on several virtual machines, which belong to the same environment, using build-deploy-test workflow](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6decc1ab-9bd1-4c8b-8b47-904a85791c9c/is-it-possible-to-run-test-on-several-virtual-machines-which-belong-to-the-same-environment-using?forum=vsmantest#4a03ddee-5829-4092-98e4-8e1d76788b58)

That all means you will end up creating two environments each consisting of one machine (one for server and one for client).
But then you will not be able to reference both environment in your build definition it you can only select one environment in *DefaultLabTemplate*.

That leads to the solution I can suggest:

1. Create two lab environments
2. Create three build definitions

   - the first one will only build your test code
   - the second one will deploy last successful build from the first one and start tests on the server environment
   - the third one will deploy last successful build from the first one and start tests on the client environment.
3. Run the first build definition automatically at night
4. Trigger the latter two simultaneously later.

It's not really nice, I know...
You will have to synchronize the build definition building the test code with the two build definitions running the tests.

I was thinking about setting up similar tests some months ago and it was the best solution I came up with...

Another option **I have not tried yet** could be:

1. Use a single test environment consisting of two machines and use different roles for them (server and client respectively).
2. In *MTM* create two *Test Settings*  (one for the server role and one for the client role).
3. Create a bat file starting tests using *tcm.exe* tool (see [How to: Run Automated Tests from the Command Line Using Tcm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465192.aspx) for more details).
   You will need two *tcm.exe* calls, one for each *Test Settings* you have created.
   Since a *tcm.exe* call just queues a test run an returns (more or less) immediately this bath file will start tests (more or less) simultaneously.
4. Create a build definition using *DefaultLabTemplate*.
   This definition will:

   - build test code
   - deploy them to both machines in your environment
   - run your bath script as the last deployment step
     (you will have to make sure this script is located on the build machine or deploy it there or make it accessible from the build machine)

As I've said, I have not tried it yet.
The disadvantage of this approach will be that you will not see the test part in the build log since the tests will not be started by means provided by *DefaultLabTemplate*. So the build will not fail when tests fail.
But you will still be able to see test outcomes in *MTM* and will have test results for each machine.

But depending on what is more important to you (having rest results or having build definition that fails if tests fail or having both) it could be a solution for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer Elena! This is a long term task and I may try one of your suggestions next time I have a go at writing some tests for my component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can with modified TestSettings file.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpu-core-machine.aspx

Comment: This will allow the tests to run simultaneously on one machine but will not allow them to run simulataneously over multiple machines in test manager. This answer does answer the title question but not my specific case so hopefully it can help someone else :